# find the last ininterrupted period of a list of months - sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with rows of year and month

Ex.

```
YearMonth
202001
202002
202003
202006
202007
202010
202011
202012
```

I would like to find the last continuous period

For the example the last continous period is: 202010 - 202012

Other case:

```
YearMonth
202001
202003
202004
202005
202006
202007
202008
```

For this the period is: 202003 - 202008

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT yearmonth
FROM   (
  SELECT yearmonth,
         TO_DATE(yearmonth, 'YYYYMM') AS dt
  FROM   table_name
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY dt
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (consecutive_months* last_month $)
  DEFINE
    consecutive_months AS ADD_MONTHS(dt, 1) = NEXT(dt)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (YearMonth) AS
SELECT 202001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202006 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202007 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202010 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202011 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202012 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | YEARMONTH |
> | --- |
> | 202010 |
> | 202011 |
> | 202012 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3e72f72d33bb7ee1b4a9f92a3635f29d)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select   
         min(YearMonth) as start_date
        ,max(YearMonth) as end_date
from      (select YearMonth
                 ,    months_between(to_date(YearMonth, 'YYYYMM'), date '2000-01-01')
                    - row_number() over (order by YearMonth) as grp
           from t 
           ) t
group by grp 
having   count(*) > 1 
order by grp desc
fetch first row only
```

| START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 202010 | 202012 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1f7d159ed0a904a7ca1cc4f55c7be9f2&hide=3)

Answer (score -1):

Well, i write a query

```
with pagos as
(
select 1 dni, 202001 pago from dual
union all
select 1, 202002 pago from dual
union all
select 1, 202003 pago from dual
union all
select 1, 202004 pago from dual
union all
select 1, 202007 pago from dual
union all
select 1, 202008 pago from dual
union all
select 1, 202009 pago from dual
)


select  distinct (min(pago) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST order by pago ) OVER (partition by dni))-1 minimo,
        max(pago) keep (DENSE_RANK LAST order by pago ) OVER (partition by dni) maximo
from 
(
    select p.*, sum(start_new_group) OVER (PARTITION BY dni ORDER BY pago desc) group_id
from
(
SELECT  dni, pago, 
        lead(pago,1) over (order by pago desc ),
        CASE WHEN pago - 1 = lead(pago,1) over (order by pago desc ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END start_new_group
        FROM pagos m 
        order by 1 desc nulls last
) p
) p
where group_id = 0
```

Result: 202007 - 202009

query result

obviusly i have to change pago - 1 por a function beacuse por example 201001 - 1 is 200912

Comment: To compute the previous calendar month you can convert `YearMonth` to a date and use a date function instead of integer arithmetic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).